# Extract data from Azure VM to Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, azure-data-factory, azcopy, azure-disk

I have been working out solution to move data from Azure VM to Google cloud storage. I see there is no connector available in ADF to move. It appears AzCopy is the only option.

I am looking at full and delta load option.
Full Data size is around : 100GB
Delta data will be around : ~1GB per day

Does anyone has any better solution?

Comment: You probably should also include details like how often you're moving the data, how much data there is etc.

Comment: Details are important. Is this one file, or 1,000 files? If one file, your only option is to copy the entire file using a tool like **gsutil**. If many files, using a sync tools, like **gsutil rsync**. Edit your question to clearly specify the problem, the goal, what you have tried, and the problem you are having.